# Insufficient Privileges issue while user trying to create the quote from an Opportunity

Tags: quote

Unable to Create Quote from An Opportunity created by a user with profile "Sales-Admin". The profile has Standard Object permission on Quote :Read, Create, Edit and View All. OWD setting for the Quote is : Controlled by Parent.  Please suggest any solution. Regards Suman.  [image]

Comment: Is the OWD for Pricebooks public read?

Comment: I would look at your formula fields and make sure the user/profile has access to those objects? I would look at 'Field Accessibility' as well under setup.

Comment: Dear Girbot, thanks for your reply. I have checked the OWD setting: Price Book Use(Default Internal Access)  Use(Default External Access).    Price Book is a custom object in my application which is lookup to Quote and user. In the user  profile Price Book has all the Permission .    Thanks Suman

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom button to create the quote and you do not submit a proper oppid in the URL I have found that Salesforce will throw an Insufficient Privileges error.  /0Q0/e?retURL={!Opportunity.Id}&oppid={!Opportunity.Id} is the minimum URL you need to provide in order to get past this error in my experience.

Hope it helps :)